# custom Ubuntu 20.04 Minimal installation on Virtualbox with Qtile - unexpected GUI

Tags: 20.04, login, gui, customization, minimal-install

***PREFACE***:

*The reason*

I am not a Linux expert, I have just started to play with Linux distros and Virtual Box.

I would love to build up a custom Ubuntu installation with:

- Lightdm
- Qtile
- Kitty

to customize a portable programming workspace since the programming language I know the most is Python, and I don't really like programming in Windows

N.B. I have already succeeded to do it on a VM with Ubuntu 18.04

*Command-line commands I have run after minimal Ubuntu Installation*

I started with installing xinit:

```
sudo apt install xinit
```

then I installed git and pip3:

```
sudo apt install git python3-pip
```

then I followed the official step-by-step Qtile installation guide (installed from source as suggested):

[http://docs.qtile.org/en/latest/manual/install/index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4bqe.png)

***THE ISSUE***:

when I reboot the VM I get this:

[login_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4bqe.png) and this [desktop-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ircsf.png) after

***2 problems*** here:

**1.** Why do I get a GUI login (that I suspect to be part of gnome desktop ) since I haven't installed one login manager like Lightdm yet

*in 18.04 this didn't happen, I just got the regular GUI-less login*

**2.** Why there is a different window manager that auto-boots different than Qtile

*in 18.04 at this point of installation I had to manually type startx on the terminal to see a GUI*

Comment: For a non-expert, you will probably prefer doing a standard installation in a VM, then in the VM, add a tiling WM of your choice. Proceeding to building your own linux setup is challenging even for experienced linux users.

Comment: @vanadium thanks for the suggestion, but I have already tried it and I am not satisfied with the result, too slow on boot and heavy for what I would love to get even more I would love to learn how really the system works :). Since i succeded in doing it with Ubuntu 18.04 i cant stand the idea to not be capable in 20.04

Comment: The login screen indeed is `gdm3`. I wonder also why that would be installed after just installing xinit. I would however think you install X with the package `xserver-common` or `xorg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The packaging for `xinit` has changed between 18.04 and 20.04.

If you `apt install xinit` on a bare Ubuntu 18.04 system, you'll get:

```
0 upgraded, 244 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
Need to get 84.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 551 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

On a bare Ubuntu 20.04 system, installing `xinit` alone pulls in a lot more:

```
0 upgraded, 513 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.
Need to get 172 MB of archives.
After this operation, 951 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

That'll be why you're seeing more things installed, and a different behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for your time :) any idea on how to bypass this problem?

Comment: Cherry pick individual packages rather than something like xinit which pulls in so much.